# Why can't .configure for libnettle 2.7.1 find -lgmp even though it is there?

Tags: linux, build, compilation

I'm trying to compile gnutls for arm on my x86 machine (Ubuntu 11.04 under VirtualBox). Right now I'm stuck compiling libnettle. *./configure* script can't find -lgmp and produces nettle without public key cryptography (no *libhogweed*) which I need. Message in *config.log* is as follows:

For x86:

```
configure:6976: checking for __gmpz_getlimbn in -lgmp
configure:7001: gcc -o conftest -L"/home/xena/gnutls/out/x86/lib/"   conftest.c -lgmp   >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:7001: $? = 1
```

And for ARM:

```
configure:6976: checking for __gmpz_getlimbn in -lgmp
configure:7001: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o conftest -L"/home/xena/gnutls/out/arm/lib/" -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb   conftest.c -lgmp   >&5
/usr/local/codesourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:7001: $? = 1
```

Those libraries are there:

```
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ ls /home/xena/gnutls/out/x86/lib/ | grep libgmp
libgmp.a
libgmp.la
libgmp.so
libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.10.1.2
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ ls /home/xena/gnutls/out/arm/lib/ | grep libgmp
libgmp.a
libgmp.la
libgmp.so
libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.10.1.2
```

And they work outside of *./configure*:

```
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ gedit conftest.c
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ gcc -o conftest -L"/home/xena/gnutls/out/x86/lib/"   conftest.c -lgmp
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ ls | grep conftest
conftest
conftest.c
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ rm conftest
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ gedit conftest.c
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o conftest -L"/home/xena/gnutls/out/arm/lib/" -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb   conftest.c -lgmp
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ ls | grep conftest
conftest
conftest.c
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ rm conftest
```

Here is my build environment:

```
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ pwd
/home/xena/gnutls
xena@xena-VirtualBox:~/gnutls$ ls
build.sh  clean.sh  gmp-5.1.2.tar.xz  gmp-help.txt  gnutls-3.2.2.tar.xz  gnutls-help.txt  nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz  nettle-help.txt
```

And my build script:

```
ROOT=/home/xena/gnutls

mkdir -p $ROOT/out

tar -xf gmp-5.1.2.tar.xz; cd gmp-5.1.2/
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/out/x86 && make && make install
cd ..; mv gmp-5.1.2 gmp-5.1.2.x86

tar -xf gmp-5.1.2.tar.xz; cd gmp-5.1.2/
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/out/arm --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" && make && make install
cd ..; mv gmp-5.1.2 gmp-5.1.2.arm



tar -xf nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz; cd nettle-2.7.1/
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/out/x86 --disable-openssl --enable-shared CFLAGS="-L\"$ROOT/out/x86/lib/\"" && make && make install
cd ..; mv nettle-2.7.1 nettle-2.7.1.x86

tar -xf nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz; cd nettle-2.7.1/
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/out/arm --disable-openssl --enable-shared --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS="-L\"$ROOT/out/arm/lib/\" -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" && make && make install
cd ..; mv nettle-2.7.1 nettle-2.7.1.arm



#tar -xf gnutls-3.2.2.tar.xz; cd gnutls-3.2.2/
#./configure --prefix=$ROOT/gnutls-out/x86 --enable-threads=posix --with-sysroot=$ROOT/out/x86 && make && make install
#cd ..; mv gnutls-3.2.2 gnutls-3.2.2.x86

#tar -xf gnutls-3.2.2.tar.xz; cd gnutls-3.2.2/
#./configure --prefix=$ROOT/gnutls-out/arm --enable-threads=posix --with-sysroot=$ROOT/out/arm --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" && make && make install
#cd ..; mv gnutls-3.2.2 gnutls-3.2.2.arm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command it will work.Give correct path to your arm built gmp library and include file.

`tar -xf nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz; cd nettle-2.7.1/`

`CFLAGS=-L/$ROOT/out/arm CPPFLAGS=-I/$ROOT/out/arm/include LDFLAGS=-L$ROOT/out/arm/lib 
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/out/arm --disable-openssl --enable-shared --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi`

Comment: Sorry I can't vote you up so I will stick with accepting. Your solution works, however for the sake of education (mine and others) coud you explain whats going on? I understand that -L flag is a linker flag so it should go to LDFLAGS, but it is only a convention - they are put in compilers command line either way. Wy the test worked standalone but not in *.configure* scrip?

Answer (score 0):

As in your case its trying to finding to link gmp. so LDFLAGS will link your library files.

To know more about how to compile you can try like below command.It shows some light on your configuartion.

`./configure --help`

here you can see various option for compilation.

`Fine tuning of the installation directories:`

This gives fine tuning of your package.

`System types:`

Under this option it will show for which machine or architecture you can build and compile.

`Some influential environment variables:`

this section gives complete control over your Flags for compiling and building your package

Answer (score 0):

So I thought I would provide you with the script that finally did it for me (it is based on vinay hunachyal'a answer). It builds gnutls with all dependencies (two mandatory ones + zlib) for x86 and ARM (i.MX25).

Mind you, that it does no error checking so it is unsafe to execute out of the box. But it is good for reference purposes.

```
echo "This file too unflexible / uncaring about return codes to be run confidently. Use it for reference purposes only!"
exit 1;

ROOT=/home/xena/gnutls

mkdir -p $ROOT/out

tar -xf gmp-5.1.2.tar.xz; cd gmp-5.1.2/
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/gmp-out/x86 --enable-cxx && make && make install
cd ..; mv gmp-5.1.2 gmp-5.1.2.x86

tar -xf gmp-5.1.2.tar.xz; cd gmp-5.1.2/
CFLAGS="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" ./configure --prefix=$ROOT/gmp-out/arm --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi && make && make install
cd ..; mv gmp-5.1.2 gmp-5.1.2.arm

cp -R $ROOT/gmp-out/* $ROOT/out



tar -xf zlib-1.2.8.tar.xz; cd zlib-1.2.8/
./configure --prefix=$ROOT/zlib-out/x86 && make && make install
cd ..; mv zlib-1.2.8 zlib-1.2.8.x86

tar -xf zlib-1.2.8.tar.xz; cd zlib-1.2.8/
CC="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CFLAGS="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" ./configure --prefix=$ROOT/zlib-out/arm && make && make install
cd ..; mv zlib-1.2.8 zlib-1.2.8.arm

cp -R $ROOT/zlib-out/* $ROOT/out



tar -xf nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz; cd nettle-2.7.1/
CFLAGS="-L$ROOT/out/x86 -I$ROOT/out/x86/include" CPPFLAGS=-I$ROOT/out/x86/include LDFLAGS=-L$ROOT/out/x86/lib LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ROOT/out/x86/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./configure --prefix=$ROOT/nettle-out/x86 --disable-openssl --enable-shared                               && make && make install
cd ..; mv nettle-2.7.1 nettle-2.7.1.x86

tar -xf nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz; cd nettle-2.7.1/
CFLAGS="-L$ROOT/out/arm -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" CPPFLAGS=-I$ROOT/out/arm/include LDFLAGS=-L$ROOT/out/arm/lib ./configure --prefix=$ROOT/nettle-out/arm --disable-openssl --enable-shared --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi && make && make install
cd ..; mv nettle-2.7.1 nettle-2.7.1.arm

cp -R $ROOT/nettle-out/* $ROOT/out



tar -xf gnutls-3.2.2.tar.xz; cd gnutls-3.2.2/
CFLAGS="-L$ROOT/out/x86 -I$ROOT/out/x86/include"  NETTLE_CFLAGS="-I$ROOT/out/x86/include/nettle" NETTLE_LIBS="-lnettle" HOGWEED_CFLAGS="-I$ROOT/out/x86/include/nettle" HOGWEED_LIBS="-lhogweed" CPPFLAGS=-I$ROOT/out/x86/include LDFLAGS=-L$ROOT/out/x86/lib LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ROOT/out/x86/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./configure --with-libz-prefix="$ROOT/out/x86/" --prefix=$ROOT/gnutls-out/x86 --enable-threads=posix --with-sysroot=$ROOT/out/x86 && make
make install # "make" fails because my system lacks makeinfo from texinfo package, but software builds correctly so I just ignore that error
cd ..; mv gnutls-3.2.2 gnutls-3.2.2.x86

tar -xf gnutls-3.2.2.tar.xz; cd gnutls-3.2.2/
CFLAGS="-L$ROOT/out/arm -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb" NETTLE_CFLAGS="-I$ROOT/out/arm/include/nettle" NETTLE_LIBS="-lnettle" HOGWEED_CFLAGS="-I$ROOT/out/arm/include/nettle" HOGWEED_LIBS="-lhogweed" CPPFLAGS=-I$ROOT/out/arm/include LDFLAGS=-L$ROOT/out/arm/lib                                                      ./configure --with-libz-prefix="$ROOT/out/arm/" --prefix=$ROOT/gnutls-out/arm --enable-threads=posix --with-sysroot=$ROOT/out/arm --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi && make
make install # same as above
cd ..; mv gnutls-3.2.2 gnutls-3.2.2.arm

cp -R $ROOT/gnutls-out/* $ROOT/out
```